# Add disabled style (css) to input type file button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am disabling a input file button in JQuery which works

```
$('#ID').attr('disabled', true)
```

However, the button still looks enabled and doesn't show the disabled style (grey)

I have tried changing the CSS

```
// Example 
$('#ID').css("background-color", 'yellow')
```

But regardless of what css I put the button never changes style.

What I can do?

the object I am using (HTML)

```
<input type="file" id="ID" class="" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Thanks

Comment: Under what circumstances are you disabling the button? This seem to work fine - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JKEKmE

Comment: What browser is this? It looks greyed out disabled in chrome and firefox to me. Maybe try and restyle the whole thing to get a dramatic result - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

Comment: @Paulie_D - I need the button disabled when the user is on a tablet, phone, device etc. its strange your example shows it more "greyed out" then what I see in Chrome. Cheers

Comment: @user3428422 http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for previous answer.

I suggest you to check [this link to know possibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) about changing a `input file`  style.

```css
div.fileinputs {
 position: relative;
}

div.fakefile {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
 position: relative;
 text-align: right;
 -moz-opacity:0 ;
 filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="fileinputs">
 <input type="file" class="file" disabled/>
 <div class="fakefile">
  <input disabled/>
  <img src="http://fptp.uthm.edu.my/mba/images/911c660826c0b.png"  style="width:30px;"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

instead of true you can use `disabled`;

```
$("#ID").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

or you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#ID").prop('disabled', true);
$("#ID").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use prop instead attr:

```
 $("#id").prop("disabled",true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fvga3xk/8/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CSS selector :disabled
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp

```
.yourButtonClass:disabled{
   background-color:#dddddd;
}
```